# UICollectionView didSelectedItemAt : first click on cell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Like written in the title, the didSelectedItemAt is bugging, but that's a little more complicated than in the title, I explain:

I try to code an application which is listing some stuffs. So I've got a ViewController with inside a TableView and a CollectionView. At the beginning the tableview's hidden is on false and the collectionview's one is on true. I've got a button on the navigation bar to switch CollectionView / TableView hidden true/false (I hope I'll be understandable with my bad English !). So the didSelectedRowAt is working well, but the didSelectedItemAt isn't. When I first click on a cell, nothing happen (on the screen at least), but the second click is working..... With the indexpath of the first click... I can't figure out why that's happening.

Does anyone know why?

Here is the some code of the app:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print (dogs[indexPath.row].name)
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DogDetailsView") as? DogDetailsView
    vc?.nameSend = dogs[indexPath.row].name
    vc?.infoSend = dogs[indexPath.row].info
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: That's because you implemented did**De**selectItemAt

Comment: Hmmm... right, what a shame to spend that time on this mistake, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong delegate method. Use following

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

The reason behind your `didDeselect` is working after the second tap is, you have turned on `allowMultilpleSelection` and whenever you tap first that cell its get selected, but you didn't implemented the correct delegate to hear that. when you tap once more, that cell is now deselected. That's why you are getting the callback in implemented method in such  way.